# Last Available value MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a requirement where in i am to extract data from a cube, within the SSRS dataset using the query builder ,with the time dimension in the result set, across a range of dates. The conditions are

1. The measures are to be displayed for each day of the date range.
2. The sub total row should have the last available measures value for that time range.
3. There is a time filter (currently a single date filter with a multi select option).

my MDX is as below.

1. The measure has a 'Sum' as the aggregation type.
2. I have a calculated measure with the scope defined as below.

   ```
    SCOPE([MEASURES].[Measure1]);   
       SCOPE([Date].[Date].MEMBERS);            
          THIS = TAIL(EXISTING ([Date].[Date].MEMBERS),1).ITEM(0)  ;            
       END SCOPE;  
    END SCOPE;
   ```

This above scope statement works perfectly. however, when i select in more that one date member this query slows WAYYYYYYY down. Performance numbers are

1. Across 1 date - 4 seconds
2. Across 2 dates - 22 minutes
3. Across 3 dates - unknown (in Hours)

This drastic degradation in performance goes away if i remove the scope statement, which makes me thing that there should be a better way to do the same. the final report query is as below.

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY
    {[Measures].[Measure1]} ON COLUMNS  
  ,NON EMPTY
    { [Dimension1].[Dimension1].[Dimension1].ALLMEMBERS*    
      [Dimension2].[Dimension2].[Dimension2].ALLMEMBERS*   
      [Dimension3].[Dimension3].[Dimension3].ALLMEMBERS*   
      [Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS  
    } ON ROWS
FROM (
      SELECT {[Date].[Date].&[2014-06-13T00:00:00]
              ,[Date].[Date].&[2014-06-16T00:00:00] } ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Cube] 
     )
```

So the question again is, ***Is there a way to do the last available value part of the scope statement so as to have a better performance? Also, if there is another way to write the final mdx that would help the performance?.***

Please let me know if there are anythings unclear regarding the question.

Thanks
Srikanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first optimization step would be to change your query to

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY
    {[Measures].[Measure1]} ON COLUMNS  
  ,NON EMPTY
    { [Dimension1].[Dimension1].[Dimension1].ALLMEMBERS*    
      [Dimension2].[Dimension2].[Dimension2].ALLMEMBERS*   
      [Dimension3].[Dimension3].[Dimension3].ALLMEMBERS*   
      {[Date].[Date].&[2014-06-13T00:00:00], [Date].[Date].&[2014-06-16T00:00:00] }
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Furthermore, I am not sure why you added the `SCOPE([Date].[Date].MEMEBER);` (probably `Date].[Date].MEMBERS`, actually). Maybe it helps to omit it and the corresponding `END SCOPE`.

Comment: Hello Frank, Thanks for the response. Please correct me if i am wrong but we wont be able to add the two date members in the ROWS section of the MDX as this list is varying. The MDX goes into a shared dataset for the usage of an SSRS report. Also, the MEMEBER was a typo error. I have made the correction on the question. The scope over the date member was to get the last value only for the aggregated rows (i.e. subtotals and totals)

Comment: @user3198708 Why can you not put a varying list into the rows? Is this a restriction of the tool you use to generate the MDX? If you can put the list into a subselect, you should also be able to put it into the rows.

Comment: Hello Frank, I had earlier marked this as the answer, however when i rechecked the query as suggested above the performance problems still persists. The query now takes 3 min from the designated 22 mins so its a significant improvement but unfortunately doesn't suffice as it degrades when more dates are included.  Also, yes, it is a limitation of the SSRS query builder that doesn't allow addition of the varying list in the rows section. The query i put up is a direct output of the designer which the clients will be using to build their report sets.

Comment: @user3198708 Without seeing the cube in detail and trying several possibilities, this is all I can do. Anyway, I am glad to hear it improved the run time by more than 80%.

Comment: Hi Frank, i agree without the entire set up its hard to suggest any further improvements. thanks for your patience and time. I'll mark this as the answer cause it did improve performance by a good amount.